# Fallo testing al iniciar sesión

Tags: java, testing

quiero testear el siguiente método de una aplicación que estoy desarrollando en Java:

```
        managerApp.getTerminal().MostrarPorPantalla("Bienvenido al formulario de registro");
        managerApp.getTerminal().MostrarPorPantalla("Por favor, inserta tu nombre real");
        String nombre = managerApp.getTerminal().RecibirPorPantalla();
        managerApp.getTerminal().MostrarPorPantalla("Perfecto, ingresa ahora un Nick");
        managerApp.getTerminal().MostrarPorPantalla("Recuerda que el Nick tiene contener más de 3 caracteres y como máximo 15");
        managerApp.getTerminal().MostrarPorPantalla("Además de contener al menos un carácter");
        String nickname = null;
        boolean requisitosCumplidos = false;
        do {
            if (managerApp.getBaseDeDatos().getUsuarios().containsKey(nickname)) {
                managerApp.getTerminal().MostrarPorPantalla("Lo sentimos, el Nickname escogido ya está en uso");
            }
            nickname = managerApp.getTerminal().RecibirPorPantalla();
            if (nickname.length() > 3 && nickname.length() <= 15 && !nickname.matches("\\d+")) {
                requisitosCumplidos = true;
            } else {
                managerApp.getTerminal().MostrarPorPantalla("Nombre inválido");
                managerApp.getTerminal().MostrarPorPantalla("Recuerda que el Nick tiene contener más de 3 caracteres y como máximo 15");
                managerApp.getTerminal().MostrarPorPantalla("debe contener al menos una letra o un caracter especial");
            }
        } while (managerApp.getBaseDeDatos().getUsuarios().containsKey(nickname) || requisitosCumplidos == false);

        managerApp.getTerminal().MostrarPorPantalla("Perfecto, ingresa ahora una contraseña");
        managerApp.getTerminal().MostrarPorPantalla("Recuerda que la contraseña debe contener entre 8 y 15 caracteres");
        String contraseña = null;
        requisitosCumplidos = false;
        do {
            contraseña = managerApp.getTerminal().RecibirPorPantalla();
            if (contraseña.length() >= 8 && contraseña.length() <= 12) {
                requisitosCumplidos = true;
            } else {
                managerApp.getTerminal().MostrarPorPantalla("Contrasena inválida");
                managerApp.getTerminal().MostrarPorPantalla("Recuerda que la contraseña debe contener entre 8 y 15 caracteres");
            }
        } while (requisitosCumplidos == false);

        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(nombre, nickname, contraseña);
        managerApp.registro(usuario);
    }
```

Para ello me he creado el siguiente Test:

```
    public void testRegistro() throws Exception {
        String input = "Jesús\n" + // nombre
                   "12\n" + // nickname inválido
                   "john12\n" + // nickname válido
                   "1234\n" + // contraseña inválida
                   "password12\n"; // contraseña válida
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
    

    ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new java.io.PrintStream(outContent));

    // Creamos un objeto ManagerApp con una base de datos vacía para el test
    File bd = new File("personas.dat");
    if (bd.exists()) {
        bd.delete();
    }
            
    ManagerAPP managerApp = new ManagerAPP();
    CuentasManager cM= new CuentasManager(managerApp);
    // Ejecutamos el método Registro()
    cM.Registro();

    // Comprobamos que se han mostrado por pantalla los mensajes correctos
    String[] expectedMessages = {
        "Bienvenido al formulario de registro",
        "Por favor, inserta tu nombre real",
        "Perfecto, ingresa ahora un Nick",
        "Recuerda que el Nick tiene contener más de 3 caracteres y como máximo 15",
        "Además de contener al menos un carácter",
        "Lo sentimos, el Nickname escogido ya está en uso",
        "Perfecto, ingresa ahora una contraseña",
        "Recuerda que la contraseña debe contener entre 8 y 15 caracteres"
    };
```

Sin embargo, al debuguear el código. Hay un fallo en la línea: "nickname = managerApp.getTerminal().RecibirPorPantalla();"

El método que me permite obtener los datos introducidos por los usuarios es el siguiente:

```
public String RecibirPorPantalla() {
        String dato;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        dato = teclado.nextLine();
        return dato;
    }
```

Me arroja como resultado, el test, que no hay siguiente línea. Cosa que no entiendo porque mi variable input del test tiene varias líneas.

[image: Fallo del test]

¿Alguien sabe qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado el fallo, para todos los que tengan el mismo fallo:

En la clase Terminal, se debe declarar el scanner como método privado, ya que sino da fallo al crear un nuevo Scanner todo el rato.